# Pyodbc - loading data inside a table causing error

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to load the data inside the table trial and it says Invalid Column name - Name.

I am passing values inside Name and Area dynamically.

```
cursor.execute("insert into trial (NameofTheProperty, AreaofTheProperty) 
              values (Name, Area)")
cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have quotes around the column values so that they are not gonna be interpreted as column names instead:

```
insert into 
    trial (NameofTheProperty, AreaofTheProperty) 
values 
    ("Name", "Area")
```

Now, since you mentioned that you dynamically insert these values into the query, you can just let your database driver handle the quotes and other things like type conversions:

```
property_name = "Name"
property_area = "Area"

cursor.execute("""
    insert into 
        trial (NameofTheProperty, AreaofTheProperty) 
    values 
        (?, ?)""", (property_name, property_area))
cnxn.commit()
```

This is called *query parameterization* and is considered the safest and the most robust way to insert values into the SQL queries. These `?` values are called "placeholders".

Note that the database driver is gonna put quotes around the string values automatically - no need to do it manually.